# Doble integral (Simpson) Python a Fortran

Tags: python, double, fortran

No logro pasar este código de Python a Fortran.
Estoy usando el método de Simpson para calcular una doble integral.
Mi código en Python funciona bien, pero no logro que quede bien en Fortran.
Este es mi código en Python

```py
import math

def f(x, y):
    return math.exp(x + y)

def approximate_double_integral(f, a, b, c, d, n, m):
    hx = (b - a) / (2 * n)
    hy = (d - c) / (2 * m)

    integral_sum = 0

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            x0 = a + 2 * i * hx
            x1 = a + (2 * i + 1) * hx
            x2 = a + (2 * i + 2) * hx

            y0 = c + 2 * j * hy
            y1 = c + (2 * j + 1) * hy
            y2 = c + (2 * j + 2) * hy

            integral_sum += f(x0, y0) + 4 * f(x1, y0) + f(x2, y0)
            integral_sum += 4 * (f(x0, y1) + 4 * f(x1, y1) + f(x2, y1))
            integral_sum += f(x0, y2) + 4 * f(x1, y2) + f(x2, y2)

    integral_value = (hx * hy / 9) * integral_sum
    return integral_value

a = 1.0
b = 3.0
c = 0.0
d = 4.0
m = 6
n = 4

result = approximate_double_integral(f, a, b, c, d, n, m)
print("El valor aproximado de la integral doble es:", result)
```

Añado ahora mi código en Fortran.
He intentado cambiar los errores que salen pero me los vuelve a marcar. La mayoría es por algún argumento pero a pesar de agregarlo no corre.

```
program ApproximateDoubleIntegral
    implicit none
    real :: a, b, c, d, hx, hy
    integer :: n, m
    real :: integral_sum, integral_value

    ! Definimos la función f(x, y)
    interface
        real function f(x, y)
            real, intent(in) :: x, y
        end function f
    end interface

    ! Definimos los parámetros de la aproximación de la integral doble
    a = 1.0
    b = 3.0
    c = 0.0
    d = 4.0
    n = 4
    m = 6

    ! Calculamos los tamaños de los subintervalos
    hx = (b - a) / (2.0 * real(n))
    hy = (d - c) / (2.0 * real(m))

    ! Inicializamos la suma de la integral
    integral_sum = 0.0

    ! Calculamos la suma de la integral aproximada
    do i = 0, n - 1
        do j = 0, m - 1
            x0 = a + 2 * i * hx
            x1 = a + (2 * i + 1) * hx
            x2 = a + (2 * i + 2) * hx

            y0 = c + 2 * j * hy
            y1 = c + (2 * j + 1) * hy
            y2 = c + (2 * j + 2) * hy

            integral_sum = integral_sum + f(x0, y0) + 4.0 * f(x1, y0) + f(x2, y0)
            integral_sum = integral_sum + 4.0 * (f(x0, y1) + 4.0 * f(x1, y1) + f(x2, y1))
            integral_sum = integral_sum + f(x0, y2) + 4.0 * f(x1, y2) + f(x2, y2)
        end do
    end do

    ! Calculamos el valor de la integral aproximada
    integral_value = (hx * hy / 9.0) * integral_sum

    ! Imprimimos el valor de la integral aproximada
    write(*,*) "El valor aproximado de la integral doble es: ", integral_value
    pause

end program ApproximateDoubleIntegral

! Definimos la función f(x, y)
real function f(x, y)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: x, y

    f = exp(x + y)

    return
end function f
```

Comment: Hola mario, puedes pasar tu codigo actual en Fortran? Asi lo podemos revisar y ver que error estas teniendo. Saludos y bienvenido!

Comment: Puede ser que tengas un problema de precision? Por que no probas en definir tus reales como real(dp)? y cuando lo inicializas le pones el _dp

Algo asi

real(dp) :: a, b, c, d, hx, hy
integer :: n, m
real(dp) :: integral_sum, integral_value

! Definimos la función f(x, y)
interface
    real function f(x, y)
        real, intent(in) :: x, y
    end function f
end interface

! Definimos los parámetros de la aproximación de la integral doble
a = 1.0_dp
b = 3.0_dp
c = 0.0_dp
d = 4.0_dp
n = 4
m = 6

Cuales son los errores que te salen?

Comment: El motivo por el que tu programa no compila es que no sabe de qué tipo son las variables  `x0`, `x1`, `x2` y sus correspondientes `y`. Para que el programa corra basta con añadirlas en la declaración de las variables reales.